# How to add notification template for the email activity through Acumatica code

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

User requirement is to create a new action button to send email from Sales order screen, when user clicks on send email we are redirecting to email activity screen and for the body i need to pass a notification template through code also when i save this email activity then this activity should create on Contact screen under activities tab.

why contacts screen is in sales order we have a custom field as Contact and it is mandatory so user want to create this activity on contacts screen i had a code till to create activity for the contact but to add sales order details as notification template is not working when i add that template manually i see blank values in the body bcz this activity is creating under contacts so i am getting blanks for the order notification template, below is my code

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> createBSEmail;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Send Email", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        public void CreateBSEmail()
        {
            ProcessBSEmail();
        }

        private void ProcessBSEmail()
        {
            if (Base.Document.Current != null)
            {
                SOOrderExt rowext = Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
                if (rowext != null)
                {
                    var targetGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CREmailActivityMaint>();
                    var message = targetGraph.Message.Insert();
                    if (rowext.UsrKWContactID != null)
                    {                        
                        Contact con = PXSelectReadonly<Contact, Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<Contact.contactID>>>>.Select(Base, rowext.UsrKWContactID);
                        if (con != null)
                        {                            
                            message.RefNoteID = con.NoteID;
                            message.BAccountID = con.BAccountID;
                            message.ContactID = con.ContactID;
                            //message.NoteID = con.NoteID;
                            message.IsIncome = false;
                            message.Subject = "Test Subjext";
                            message.MailTo = con.EMail != null ? con.EMail : string.Empty;
                                targetGraph.Message.Update(targetGraph.Message.Current);
                                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(targetGraph, true, "Email") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}
                    }
                }
            }
        }


Also, here if i pass salesorder noteid then i am able to get the values for the order notification template when i add it, but then the activity is creating for the order not to the contact.

So how i can resolve this i need to create the activity for the contact and through code i need to pass order details using notification template.


Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: There are many unrelated questions wrapped into a single one. Consider asking more focused questions so we can provide answer on a single issue. It's not obvious which part needs to be done programmatically and which one should be done by user. Opening send email activity page is different than actually sending the email.

Comment: Hi @HuguesBeauséjour i have modified my question above please check once and help me to resolve this